# How to make the sliding window in Apache Flink to slide only after the window size is reached?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

private DataStream buySideVolumeWMA(DataStream buyPressureTradeStream) {

```
    Integer windowSize = 3;
    Integer windowslide = 1;

    DataStream<Double> buySideVolumeWMAStream = buyPressureTradeStream.countWindowAll(windowSize, windowslide)
            .apply(new AllWindowFunction<String, Double, GlobalWindow>() {

                @Override
                public void apply(GlobalWindow window, Iterable<String> values, Collector<Double> out)
                        throws Exception {
                    Double buySideVolumeWMA = 0.0;
                    Integer weight = windowSize;
                    Integer numerator = 1;

                    for (String tradeString : values) {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(tradeString);
                        Double tradeVolume = (Double) json.get("Volume");
                        buySideVolumeWMA += ((tradeVolume * numerator) / weight);
                        slf4jLogger.info("tradeVolume " + tradeVolume + " , " + "numerator , " + numerator
                                + " weight , " + weight + " buySideVolumeWMA " + buySideVolumeWMA);
                        numerator++;

                    }
                    numerator = 1;

                    out.collect(buySideVolumeWMA / 2);
                    buySideVolumePressure = buySideVolumeWMA / 2;
                    // slf4jLogger.info("buySideVolumePressure :" +
                    // buySideVolumePressure);


    buySideVolumeWMAStream.print().setParallelism(5);

    return buySideVolumeWMAStream;

}
```

========================================================================       In this program I am using a window size of 3 and slide size 1. I want it to start sliding once it receives streaming data of count 3 and then only start slide by 1. But what happens is that my program start to slide immediately as it receives first data and then it slides for every single data it receives.So how to make it slide only after it receive data of count 3 and then slide by 1?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you detail more what is your issue. You should add an example of what you get and what you want.

Comment: @ImbaBalboa . Thanks for your reply.I have added some more details regarding my issue below my program.Could you please guide me in this?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add an offset to your window. This is the third argument of the Window command. This way you could start later in my opinion.

Example from the documentation :

```
// sliding processing-time windows offset by -8 hours
input
    .keyBy(<key selector>)
    .window(SlidingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.hours(12), Time.hours(1), Time.hours(-8)))
    .<windowed transformation>(<window function>);
```

To learn more : https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/windows.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this is not a feature of sliding windows as of Nov 2019 and in Flink 1.9.1. I understand that this is because the window objects are separate and do not share any state. For example, objects in windows are copied and stored once for each window and key if using a keyed stream.

The below filter keeps enough state to ignore the first n messages that it receives. If using a keyed stream -- as in `.keyBy(...)` -- a separate counter will be kept for each key because this is how Flink manages the ValueState objects.

```
  /**
   * This filter suppresses the first n messages (inclusive of n). This behavior may be desired for use with sliding
   * windows when no output is desired until the full size of the window is reached.
   *
   * Example usage:
   * .filter(new SuppressFirstNFromSlidingWindow[(String, Int)](5))
   */
  class SuppressFirstNFromSlidingWindow[T](nToSuppress: Int) extends RichFilterFunction[T] {

    private var state_allowAll: ValueState[Boolean] = _
    private var state_numberSkipped: ValueState[Int] = _

    override def filter(value: T): Boolean = {

      if (state_allowAll.value()) return true

      val numberSkipped = state_numberSkipped.value()
      if (numberSkipped < nToSuppress) {
        state_numberSkipped.update(numberSkipped + 1)
        false
      } else {
        state_allowAll.update(true)
        true
      }
    }

    override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {

      state_allowAll = getRuntimeContext.getState(
        new ValueStateDescriptor[Boolean]("allowAll", createTypeInformation[Boolean])
      )

      state_numberSkipped = getRuntimeContext.getState(
        new ValueStateDescriptor[Int]("numberSkipped", createTypeInformation[Int])
      )
    }
  }
```